# Cannot get option text when using dynamic select dropdown in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here, I am getting options text in select dropdown using jquery

```
tmp_selected  = $('#new_autoccType option:selected').text();
```

But, I can't able to equal the strings, getting correct options text in alert.
It doesn't goes to if loop if the strings are equal.
This is not working only if I use dynamic options value, if it is static, I can get the values.

Could somebody help?

```js
var def_expval="";
var newEC = 1;
var strNewCC = 1;


data = '<select class="tablefont" name="new_autoccType" id="new_autoccType">'; 
 data+='<option value= '+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+newEC+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+' > '+"New Electronic Check"+' </option>';
    data+='<option value= '+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+strNewCC+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+','+def_expval+' > '+"New Debit/Credit Card"+' </option>';
data +='</select>';

$("#somedivs").html(data);


$('#new_autoccType').change(function() {  
            selOption =  $(this).val();
             tmp_selected  = $('#new_autoccType option:selected').text();
      alert(tmp_selected); 
      if(tmp_selected == "New Electronic Check")
            {
              alert("inside ec");
     //some operations 
            }
          if (tmp_selected == "New Credit/Debit Card")
            {
           alert("inside cc");
           //some operations
            } 
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="somedivs"></div>
```

[Static JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hs74sby1/7/)

[Dynamic JS FIDDLE - PROBLEM HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hs74sby1/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove spaces, for this operation you can use [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function

```
var tmp_selected = $('#new_autoccType option:selected').text().trim();
```

Also for the second condition change text

from `if (tmp_selected == "New Credit/Debit Card")` to `if (tmp_selected == "New Debit/Credit Card")`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hs74sby1/13/

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces in your strings use $.trim(tmp_selected) function to remove spaces

```
if(tmp_selected == " New Electronic Check ")
           {
                alert("inside ec");
                //some operations   
           }
     if (tmp_selected == " New Debit/Credit Card ")
           {
             alert("inside cc");
            //some operations
           }
```

[Working Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hs74sby1/12/)

Answer (score 1):

use `trim()` to remove spaces from the selected text like this:

```
 var tmp_selected = $('#new_autoccType option:selected').text().trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hs74sby1/11/)

try this

```
$('#new_autoccType').change(function() {  
               selOption =  $(this).val();
               tmp_selected  = $('#new_autoccType option:selected').text();
               alert(tmp_selected); 
               if(tmp_selected.trim() == "New Electronic Check")
               {
                    alert("inside ec");
                    //some operations   
               }
               if (tmp_selected.trim() == "New Debit/Credit Card")
               {
                 alert("inside cc");
                //some operations
               } 
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $.trim(tmp_selected) for comapring, remove space

```
$('#new_autoccType').change(function() {  
           selOption =  $(this).val();
            tmp_selected  = $('#new_autoccType option:selected').text();
           alert(tmp_selected); 
           if($.trim(tmp_selected) == "New Electronic Check")
           {
                alert("inside ec");
                //some operations   
           }
      if ($.trim(tmp_selected) == "New Credit/Debit Card")
           {
             alert("inside cc");
            //some operations
           } 
    }).change();
```